# Deleted complete Maven Dependencies folder by mistake

Tags: maven

Maven Dependencies folder disappears in my project. I tried to cleanup and build the project again to get back the dependencies, but still I'm not able to?

Now, if you see the whole project has lots of errors in it as it no longer recognizes the annotations, import statements and so on..

[Removed maven dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGfnC.png)

I want to get back all my dependencies again. Please help.

Comment: Please provide more details. What exactly happens when you build the project? Do you get any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: suppose you have a `pom.xml` in the root of the project. Just do a `mvn clean install` in the console and all the dependencies will be back.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, yes, all the java POJO's have errors in there on every annotation since there are no dependencies.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with answers to all of my questions.

Comment: Included more details to my question by adding an image. Anyways, the problem was solved by updating project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally resolved it by updating my project configuration as below:

Right click on Project --> Maven --> Update Project

[Restoring Maven dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsasS.jpg)

Comment: Don't know why it didn't do the trick for me after I had deleted only one dependency. However, when I deleted another one it worked and fixed both.